# MongoEngine Query EmbeddedDocumentField

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I have a MongoEngine model definition that looks like so:

```
class Kennel(Document):
    locations = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Location), required=True)
```

Which creates documents that look like so:

```
{
    'locations': {
        'location_43243': {
            "dogs": [{"name": "clifford", "color": "red"}, {"name": "old yeller", "color": "yellow"}]
        },
        'location_54747': {
            "dogs": [{"name": "bolto", "color": "grey"}]
        }
    }
}
```

Given that I have a location id (e.g. location_43243), I would like to return the documents whose value for that id have a dog with a certain name. For example, given the name "clifford" and the location id "location_43243", I should return the above document.

Any help is appreciated.